# Don't show ImagePicker in WKWebView iOS

Tags: ios, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I would like to have a `WKWebView` that does not display the ImagePicker but uses an image I have selected. Is something like this possible?

[image: The Picker I wanna to hide]

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score -1):

This image picker show on Long press event. Just remove `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` from your webview. Use following wkwebview extension.

```
extension WKWebView {

/// disable long press on Wkwebview    
func removeLongTapGestures() {
    for subView in self.scrollView.subviews {
        if let recogniserz = subView.gestureRecognizers {
            for recogniser in recogniserz {
                if recogniser is UILongPressGestureRecognizer {
                    subView.removeGestureRecognizer(recogniser)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

call this function `removeLongTapGestures` in webview `didFinish` delegate method.

```
webView.removeLongTapGestures()
```

Comment: This isn't what I was looking for. I have a website where I want to upload a picture and want to use a picture from Xcode. Removing the gesture won't do me any good.